# i have to access/commit/update SVN repository in WPF application using SVN API or libraries

Tags: c#, .net, svn

Any GOOD libraries available to access SVN from .net application (using C#). The only 3 I found so far that I will be trying out is:

- [SVN#](http://www.softec.st/en/OpenSource/ClrProjects/SubversionSharp/SubversionSharp.html)
- [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/)
- [NSvn](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PowerShellAnkhSVNAndSubversion.aspx)

I want to create a very simple SVN client!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

SharpSvn was desiged for .Net 2.0 and Subversion 1.5 and later. It integrates all subversion dependencies in a single set of dll that is directly usable from .Net (XCopy deployable). One of the other strong points of SharpSvn is that it hides all memory management and transforms Subversion errors in exceptions, and more importantly vice versa. (Makes debugging callbacks very easy)

NSvn was used by AnkhSVN before AnkhSVN 2.0. It moved to SharpSvn after that.

The IronSvn project on Codeplex closed down. (It suggests using SharpSvn).

Svn# and its 2.0 successor Svn.Net are plain wrappers of the Subversion C api. They required the binaries of a subversion release to work. And you must manage the apr pools and some of the apr collection marshalling yourself from managed code. This is the only cross platform solution in this list. (Works just as well on linux)

Comment: You got my vote ; I use SharpSvn in my project. The library is well designed and the support is great: thanks! That's the most efficient solution to use svn from a managed client.

Comment: Just don't have your repo on the root of a drive (c:\ or d:\ for example) or SharpSvn will blow up into a thousand shards of glass and tear a new whole in the fabric of space and time.

Comment: Doesn't work on Mono because it depends on VC++ toolchain. Would be great if there were completely managed options.

Answer (score 9):

I used SharpSvn. It was easy to integrate and works well for me. If you need some sample code have a look at this project https://github.com/bhank/SVNCompleteSync.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using SharpSVN at the moment - works fine for what I need (although it is for an automated process, so no UI work necessary).

Answer (score 2):

- what about NSvn which is (if i'm not wrong) also the core of ankhsvn (check out the tigris.org website for more information)

Comment: NSvn has been replaced by SharpSvn in the 2.0 series. It's development has discontinued.

Comment: AnkhSVN - http://ankhsvn.net/ or http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/