# Does anyone know of a good C# API for Subversion?

Tags: c#, .net, svn, sharpsvn

I'm looking to make calls out to a subversion repository, but I would like to write it in C#. Does anyone know of any good libraries?

Comment: Take a look at the <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211765/svn-libraries-for-net">SVN Libraries for .NET?</a> question.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930053/sample-code-for-subversion

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Have a look at [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/). This is an open-source binding of the Subversion Client API for .Net 2.0 applications.

For example, this library is used by the [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) Visual Studio Add-In.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you look at the [Tortoise SVN source code](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/).

It is mostly in C++, but since it is all done in VS, it should be easy to wrap up and use much of the code again.

You can also try [SubversionSharp](http://www.softec.st/en/OpenSource/ClrProjects/SubversionSharp/SubversionSharp.html) if you want less heavy lifting (however it is not yet a stable release, so be cautious).

Answer (score 1):

How about [SubversionSharp.](http://www.softec.st/en/OpenSource/ClrProjects/SubversionSharp/SubversionSharp.html)

Comment: You should mention that this is not a stable, released product.