# Sample code for Subversion

Tags: c#, svn, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anyone know of a good C# API for Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481247/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-c-sharp-api-for-subversion)

Can anyone point to me the starting point for Subversion using C# APIs

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/). It's an open-source binding of the Subversion Client API for .Net 2.0