# Are there Windows API binaries for Subversion or do I have to build SVN to call the API from Windows C++?

Tags: c++, svn, winapi

I want to call a Subversion API from a Visual Studio 2003 C++ project.

I know there are threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795096/how-to-programatically-do-file-versioning-with-svn-and-net), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211765/svn-libraries-for-net), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481247/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-c-api-for-subversion), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930053/sample-code-for-subversion) that tell how to get started with C#.NET on Windows (the consensus seems to be [SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/), which I've used easily and successfully on another project) but that's not what I want.

I've read the [chapter on using APIs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.developer.usingapi.html) in the red-bean book which says:

> Subversion is primarily a set of C libraries, with header (.h) files that live in the subversion/include directory of the source tree. These headers are copied into your system locations (e.g., /usr/local/include) when you build and install Subversion itself from source. These headers represent the entirety of the functions and types meant to be accessible by users of the Subversion libraries.

I'd like to use [CollabNet Subversion](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) but there doesn't seem to be API binary downloads, and I'd just as soon not build the whole thing if I can avoid it.

Considering another approach, I found [RapidSVN's C++ API](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/svncpp.html), but it doesn't appear to offer Windows API binaries either and seems to require building SVN (which I would be willing to do as a last choice if RapidSVN's API is higher-level than the stock SVN offering.)

*Does calling the API from C++ in Windows have to be this much more work compared to using SharpSvn under .NET, or is there something I haven't found that would help me achieve my goal?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the dev (e.g. `svn-win32-1.6.16_dev.zip`) package from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/). Probably download also the binaries (e.g. `svn-win32-1.6.16.zip`) of the tools (DLLs are there).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that. Your "dev" link and your "binaries" link are the same - did you intend that?

Comment: I am able to get a struct svn_version_t * from a call to svn_client_version() and the struct values are 1,6,3 so I'm off and running. Thanks again! Accepting your answer.

Comment: Seems like those links are broken.  Milen - could you update your answer?