# Where can I find the SVN .lib files?

Tags: c++, svn, dll

I'm trying to write an application that wraps SVN. I've downloaded the binaries for it, and all I've found are DLLs.

Is there somewhere where I can find the .lib files? Or do I need to use LoadLibrary and find each method manually? Or do I just need to include the SVN source code, which would be a pain to maintain.

EDIT:

I have found a download that has all the .libs and include files after following this question, anyone else trying to find an answer should look here:

For anyone else who may be looking for the same thing, there is a download here that has everything you want!

[Are there Windows API binaries for Subversion or do I have to build SVN to call the API from Windows C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088520/are-there-windows-api-binaries-for-subversion-or-do-i-have-to-build-svn-to-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that what you want is readily available as very few people use that. You are searching for a developer build for svn.

Your best chances are to download the source code for svn and compile it yourself. That way the lib files will be generated and you will be able to link against them.

EDIT : Another option you have is to use another layer of wrapper around SVN and use something like [rapidSVN API](http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/svncpp.html). This will expose most common svn features and you don't have to handle the svn source code.

EDIT2 : I think that they moved to github
https://github.com/RapidSVN/RapidSVN

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at them, this will help since it's C++ anyways.

Comment: Damn, it looks like the download was taken off, and the SVN repo needs a password.

Comment: Ah thanks again! Unfortunately it's GNU GPL, so I may not be able to use it, but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It was my understanding that linking to GPL was ok. : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL_linking_exception Just don't include the sources directly and include a notice in your licenses that you are linking to a GPL project.

Comment: A good example for this is MySQL, which is ok to use in projects but not copy directly from it

Comment: Hm you might be right. The company I work for requires their lawyers look over every license so I'll have to wait for their input if we decide to take this route.

Answer (score -1):

DLL's are libs, but they are dynamic libs, loaded and executed during run time.  Lib files, however, are libraries that have been loaded into the compiler and used to compile the binaries.  In your case, there wouldn't be lib files because the .exe binaries already have the libs built into them.  Where-as, you do get the DLL's because they aren't built into the binaries, but instead are loaded somewhere inside the binary during execution.

There is no reason to include the .lib's in a binary download since the binaries don't need them anymore to function.  The only reason you would need .lib files is if you had the rest of the source code in order to build your own .exe again.

Comment: My reasoning is that if I'm to develop against the SVN api, and I have all the headers to include, I still need to function definitions somewhere or else I'll get linker errors.

Comment: That may be true, but you said you downloaded the binaries package for it, that usually means only the stuff you need to run it.  If you want libs and headers (did the headers come in that package?  I would think that is weird) you will need to get a developer SDK of their stuff (if they even have that).