# Tortoisesvn API for C#.NET

Tags: api, tortoisesvn

How to integrate tortoisesvn Diff API(tool) for C#.Net?
I should be able to use DIFF Tool in Tortoisesvn in my C# application.

Comment: Are you actually looking for an API to the TortoiseSVN tool or are you instead looking for a C# API to Subversion? If the latter is the case, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481247/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-c-api-for-subversion.

Comment: Iam looking for a API to the DIFF Tool in Tortoisesvn(for comparing 2 different versions of a file visually)

Answer (score 4):

The **TortoiseMerge** tool (used for merging and diffing) is a standalone application. There are only a few [command line options](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseMerge_en/tme-automation.html) you can use to start the tool with the files/folders to diff.

Same is true for the the image diff tool **TortoiseIDiff** which also has a command line interface described [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation-idiff.html).

But there's no API to directly integrate them.

Answer (score 0):

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481247/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-c-api-for-subversion/481310#481310):

> Have a look at SharpSVN. This is an open-source binding of the
>   Subversion Client API for .Net 2.0 applications.
>
> For example, this library is used by the AnkhSVN Visual Studio Add-In.