# How to get a list of uncommitted files from tortoise or svn

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn

I am writing a c# app that needs to look at a folder and get a list of files that need to be committed.  Tortoise SVN is guaranteed to be installed on the machine.  How can I get that list programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that TortoiseSVN can help you with this, but it should not be too much effort doing it yourself using a C# SVN library.

Take a look at this question: [Does anyone know of a good C# API for Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/481247/50079).

Comment: Ah, I overlooked this one when I posted my link as a comment to the question.

Comment: Seems like using SharpSVN would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

call `svn.exe status` and capture and parse the output

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe TortoiseSVN has an API that allows external applications to retrieve information from it, which is what you would need to do this properly. The best you can do with what is provided is use the [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) command-line utility to determine if any local modifications exist in a given working copy.