# Automating Subversion with C#

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anyone know of a good C# API for Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481247/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-c-sharp-api-for-subversion)

I'm designing a document library, and I'd like to use Subversion as the version control system. How can I automate tasks like check-in, check-out and diff from C#? Does Tortoise perhaps offer some help with this?

TIA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about [sharpsvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Give a look to this question:

- [SVN Libraries for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211765)

Answer (score 2):

Subversion is completely command line driven.  TortoiseSVN masks this for us windows users. Simply call the command line commands from within your C# program.

Comment: Noteworthy: by using the --xml parameter you get the output as XML which is definitely easier to parse than plain console output. I was using this in a C#-based server hook that was sending commit messages to our bug tracker...

Answer (score 1):

You can write server-side or client-side hooks with C#.  on the server side you just need to write an app that takes the connect number of parameters give it the name of the hook and put it in the hooks folder.  On the client side you will do the same but you need to hell Tortoise were to find the app.

(this is assuming you want to get information from SNV in to the content management.  You might want to look at the [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625406/using-tortoisesvn-via-command-line) tools or [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) to go the other way around)

- [Server Side Hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository-hooks.html)
- [Client Side Hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use the commandline from your app?

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svn.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this blog post about [Creating your own custom Subversion management layer](http://www.troyhunt.com/2009/10/creating-your-own-custom-subversion.html). In short, [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) is your best bet but you'll still have some work to do.