# Best client for SVN / WIndows for READ ONLY ;)?

Tags: svn

- Not interested in any source control OR shell integration.

This is basically to make regular gets on certain third party archives. I would really prefer not to deal with SVN in any way in my shell or visual studio.

Native / C# preferred (as i have those runtimes already installed).

Anyone a recommendation under those circumstances?

Comment: svn, as the tag says ;) and the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the basic subversion client binary, a compiled Windows package with installer can be downloaded at [CollabNet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/).

Just add the program path to `$PATH` and you can do a `svn update` or `svn checkout` from anywhere on your system. You can even automate the processes using batch files or Windows scripts.

Comment: I agree. I "readonly" client (if there even is such a thing) would probably not differ from a "regular" client. You just dont use the write commands.

Comment: Actually it is - a readonly client does not have to do any change tracking. I ended up with SmartSvn which has a "download" mode (gets the archive, no additional directories, caches etc. are created - so 0 overhead). Shell integration can be selected off at install.

Comment: @TomTom I think you're being too overhead sensitive here. So what if there's 500k of unused libraries on your machine? On the other hand, I can somewhat see your point about caching, auth caches, `.svn` directories (although that could be sorted by using `svn export`). Anyway, glad it worked out for you. Care to add a link to the product you ended up using, for future generations?

Comment: Not really, but I am pullin a couple of third party stuff from SVN folders - without ever changing them etc. I Dont want to deal with all that crap around ,especially because one of the folders already has about 300mb (no joke) with all the documentation being part of the trunk ;) http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [TortoiseSVN](http://www.tortoisesvn.net). Best integration everything needed.

Comment: SUCKS is my word for it. SHell integration is explicitely not wanted, as is the ridiculous subfolder mechanism. Had to use it at a customer, made me puke, sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

You said "I would really prefer not to deal with SVN in any way in my shell or visual studio" and "C# preferred".  Have you considered writing your own app using the [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) library?  That way you could taylor it to exactly your requirements.

Also see this question:
[SVN Libraries for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211765/svn-libraries-for-net)

Comment: Actually I ended up with SmartSvn which has a "download" mode (gets the archive, no additional directories, caches etc. are created - so 0 overhead). Shell integration can be selected off at install.