# Call AnkhSVN commands in C#

Tags: c#, macros, ankhsvn

Is there a way that I can call the same commands that `Ankh SVN` uses, within `C#` code?

For example, can I call the same functionality that adds a solution to a subversion from code?

I am writing `Visual Studio` addin that will allow me to reuse a solution template, rather than having to recreate the same basic structure again and again.

Is there a list of macros or similar that `AnkhSVN` would map its commands to - i.e. Add solution to subversion?

I have looked around for templates or addins that would do the job for me but have decided to make my own, so am not looking for links to any other templates or addins.

**Edit**: I think that I may also be able to use `this._applicationObject` in my addin to add my solution to subversion as I would if I were manually doing so using Visual Studio.

Comment: It's probably out of date, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211765/svn-libraries-for-net - There may be new libraries which have been introduced since, but at that time everything had standardized on SharpSvn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [SharpSvn](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) to work with Subversion directly from within your C# extension.